# Finding an element of $X$ that is not in $W$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $X=Y=\Bbb N$ where $\Bbb N$ is the set of natural numbers.
Define $f:X\to Y$ by $f(x)=2x$ and define $g: Y\to X$ by $g(y)=3y$.
Let $W = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty g(fg)^n(Y-D)$, where $D=f(X)$.

$W$ is a subset of $X$. Find an element of $X$ that is not in $W$. Explain.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Sorry, this is unreadable. Regards

Comment: did that help at all..

Comment: Yes, that helped. There is now only one reason left to close it. Please explain what you've tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: I started with a picture of the function but i am not understanding how to apply the given functions of f and g to the problem, composition g(fg) part

Answer (score 1):

HINT: The first step is to identify the set $D$: $D=f[X]=f[\Bbb N]=\{2n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, so $D$ is the set of even natural numbers, and $Y\setminus D=\Bbb N\setminus D$ is the set of odd natural numbers, which for convenience I’ll call $A$. You need to find $W=\bigcup_{n\ge 0}g(fg)^n[A]$.

For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $A_n=g(fg)^n[A]$, so that $W=\bigcup_{n\ge 0}A_n$. $A_0=g[A]$, $A_1=gfg[A]=gf[A_0]$, $A_2=gfgfg[A]=gf[A_1]$, and in general you should have no trouble proving by induction that $A_{n+1}=gf[A_n]$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$.

Now identify exactly what natural numbers are in $A_0$: $A_0=g[A]=\{3n:n\in A\}$, so $A_0$ is the set of odd multiples of $3$. Thus, $A_0=\{3(2k+1):k\in\Bbb N\}$.

Now suppose that we’ve identified the members of some $A_n$. Then

$$A_{n+1}=gf[A_n]=g[\{2a:a\in A_n\}]=\{3\cdot2a:a\in A_n\}=\{6a:a\in A_n\}\;:$$

to get $A_{n+1}$ from $A_n$, just multiply everything in $A_n$ by $6$. In particular,

$$A_1=\{6a:a\in A_0\}=\{6\cdot3(2k+1):k\in\Bbb N\}=\{2\cdot3^2(2k+1):k\in\Bbb N\}\;.$$

Now calculate $A_2$ and, if necessary, $A_3$, expressing them in the way that I expressed $A_1$; you should spot a simple pattern that you can prove by induction. Once you have that, you should have no trouble finding a natural number that is not in $W$.